# How to uninstall Miniconda on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, miniconda

I have installed Miniconda in my Ubuntu Linux distribution. There is a conflict with the Python version of Linux.
I would like to uninstall Miniconda. I follow the instruction in https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall.

```
$ anaconda-clean
Delete .conda? (y/n): y
Backup directory: /home/user1/.anaconda_backup/2017-09-14T221900
Error: Unable to move /home/user1/.conda
Delete .continuum? (y/n): y
Error: Unable to move /home/user1/.continuum
```

I have the Miniconda bin in the `/usr/local/bin/miniconda`. There is nothing in the folder `/home/user1`, and I cannot give some parameters to anaconda-clean.

How can I remove Miniconda properly? Remove directly the folder `/usr/local/bin/miniconda`?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Just delete the folder. `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/miniconda`.

Comment: I am curious about the python conflict issue.  Can you give some more detail as to the nature of the conflict, either in your question or here in a comment?  I would think it could be resolved without uninstalling miniconda.

Comment: I try to start the framework Flask from ipython and from bash command (python test.py). It works for ipython but not from the bash. When I look into the PYTHONPATH, I saw that miniconda is in the path for the bash and not for ipython.

Answer (score 4):

I'm wondering why you're getting those errors: are you actually using the user1 account or is there perhaps some other reason there would be an issue with permissions on those files?

In any case, to uninstall Miniconda from Ubuntu you need three things:

**1. Remove configuration files**

Even if it's not working properly, you could still use `anaconda-clean` to get an idea of which configuration files/directories are relevant (e.g., ".conda/", ".continuum/") and remove them manually.

**2. Remove miniconda directory**

Delete the Miniconda directory with `rm -rf *directory_path*` as was suggested in the comments.

**3. Restore original .bashrc**

Miniconda probably updated `~/.bashrc` to add itself to PATH. It also probably made a backup of the original (something like `~/.bashrc-miniconda.bak`), which you could simply restore; if not, you can manually remove the relevant line from .bashrc. It might look like one of the following:

```
export PATH="/home/user1/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
```